# is MPIR's floating point type inaccurate?

Tags: c, floating-point, mpfr

I'm just starting with MPIR and I'm executing this code:

```
mpf_t t2;
mpf_init2(t2, 10000);
mpf_set_d(t2, 5.999999999999);
gmp_printf("fixed point mpf %.40Ff", t2);
```

The output is:

```
fixed point mpf 5.9999999999989999110994176589883863925934
```

This seems highly innacurate, although I've set the precision to 10000. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hint: What datatype is `5.999999999999`?

Comment: It is a double?
Are you alluding to the format specifier?

Comment: You should really use MPFR instead of MPF. Of course, you'll still have the issue that the value is converted to a `double` first. Also, this behavior is mentioned in the MPFR manual, where it is recommended to use `mpfr_set_str` instead of functions like `mpfr_set_d` in order to avoid this conversion to a low precision format.

Comment: Yes, MPFR would be cool to use. But I'm working on Windows and I haven't found an easy solution to install MPF/MPFR so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`5.999999999999` is a `double`. Now, a `double` can't actually hold the value 5.999999999999, but it can hold the value 5.9999999999989999110994176589883863925934 which is almost exactly the same - and you'd never notice the difference, right?

Use `mpf_set_str` instead:

```
mpf_set_str(t2, "5.999999999999", 10);
```

(10 is the base, in this case decimal)

Comment: Ah yes of course. It's too late, I have to go to bed. Thank!

Comment: Strictly speaking, a `double` cannot hold either of the values that you say, but it can hold 5.9999999999989999110994176589883863925933837890625, which gets rounded up to 5.9999999999989999110994176589883863925934 when printed with that number of significant decimal digits.